# ReactJS _ Promise - Is it okay to initialize function in the componentDidMount() methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm building an app with some promises to handle my animation. Since few trials I get the following error:

> Warning: Can’t call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a 
>   no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead,
>   assign to this.state directly or define a state = {}; class property
>   with the desired state in the App component.”

To solutionate this warning I have inserted my Promise's function inside the componentDidMount() method hence ensuring the component has mounted when called as following:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setExitAnimation=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{  
        {code here...}
 }
```

I'm tring to do that: http://mverissimo.github.io/tweenslideshow, here my sandbox: if you are interested:  http://codesandbox.io/s/64l5xyp2mz - there is a bugg on the image component which follow the other element animation instead of trigger its specific sequence.

Here my reactJS snippet concerning my promises:

```
 // set animation name 
      // => then callback other functions with the animation name
 setAnimation=()=>{   
    // appreciate if enter or exit flow
    if(this.state.exitLoop){ 
      // if exit flow, trigger the setting for exiting's animation
      this.setExitAnimation.then((anim)=> {  
        // then callback function to trigger the relevant animation °for image or text°
        this.state.elementType === "text"?
          this.triggerTextAnimation(anim)  
          :
          this.triggerImageAnimation(anim) 
      })
    }else{ 
      // if enter flow, trigger the setting for entering's animation
      this.setEnterAnimation.then((anim)=>{ 
        // then callback function to trigger the relevant animation °for image or text° 
        this.state.elementType === "text"?
          this.triggerTextAnimation(anim)  
          :
          this.triggerImageAnimation(anim) 
      });
    }  
  }

// set animation' name in case of enteringOnPage's flow
setEnterAnimation=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{  
  console.log("in setEnterAnimation")
  // appreciate the element type to select which update todo on state
     // also appreciate the specific animation sequence to set on the state
  if(this.state.elementType ==="text"){
    if(this.state.currentView % 2 === 0){ 
      this.setState({textAnimation:enterDownAnimation});
      resolve(enterDownAnimation);
    }else{
        this.setState({textAnimation:enterUpAnimation}) 
    }    
  }else{ 
    switch(this.state.currentView){ 
      case 0: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:enterSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 1: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:enterUpAnimation});
        break;
      case 2: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:enterDownAnimation});
        break;
      case 3: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:enterSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 4: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:enterUpAnimation});
        break;
      default:
        console.log("no animation found")
        break; // test return
    }
  }
})

// set animation' name in case of exitingPage's flow
setExitAnimation=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{  
   // appreciate the element type to select which update todo on state
      // also appreciate the specific animation sequence to set on the state
  if(this.state.elementType ==="text"){
    if(this.state.currentView % 2 === 0){ 
        this.setState({textAnimation:exitDownAnimation});
        resolve(exitDownAnimation);
    }else{
        this.setState({textAnimation:exitUpAnimation});
        resolve(exitDownAnimation);
    }
  }else{ 
    console.log("currentView: ", this.state.currentView)
    switch(this.state.currentView){ 
      case 0: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:exitSideAnimation});
        resolve(exitSideAnimation)
        break;
      case 1: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:exitUpAnimation});
        resolve(exitUpAnimation)
        break;
      case 2: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:exitDownAnimation});
        resolve(exitDownAnimation)
        break;
      case 3: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:exitSideAnimation});
        resolve(exitSideAnimation)
        break;
      case 4: 
        this.setState({imageAnimation:exitUpAnimation});
        resolve(exitUpAnimation)
        break;
      default:
        console.log("no animation found")
        break; // test return
    }
  }
})
```

What do you think about this solution in a Promise context? More generally appreciated?

Any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: Please share the relevant code you have inside promise

Comment: okay done, I have include the promise's snippet

Comment: Why are you even using promises here at all? There doesn't appear to be anything asynchronous in the code.

Comment: thanks for comment, I want my code have the time to get the new animation's name, then return it to my function to trigger the new animation name

Comment: @Bergi you have some specific advice to share with us maybe?

Comment: @Webwoman I can't give specific advice if I don't know what you are trying to do. I would drop all the promise code completely, and it seems like you don't even need the `setEnterAnimation` and `setExitAnimation` properties. What are you doing with them, what do you think you need them for?

Comment: I'm tring to do that: https://mverissimo.github.io/tweenslideshow/, here my sandbox: if you are interested, I will add some comments :)  https://codesandbox.io/s/64l5xyp2mz - there is a bugg on the image component which follow the other element animation instead of trigger its specific sequence.

Comment: @Bergi the setEnterAnimation and setExitAnimation are to set the type of animation sequence to trigger

Comment: But wouldn't a simple boolean variable (`isEntering`, `isExiting`) suffice for this? Why do you think you need promises for this? What exactly do you mean by "trigger"? Are the promises not always resolved immediately?

Comment: Is because my component's state was set too late and the animation gone with the former state, so I have used promise to ensure the animation start after having wait for the new state defined in setEnterAnimation and setExitAnimation

Answer (score 2):

In general, you did right. It's safe to have async operation(s) in `componentDidMount`, since that lifecycle hook doesn't prevent rendering. The only caveat here is that it runs only once.

If you need to react to props changes, you may consider using `componentDidUpdate`, nb it has opposite caveat, runs only when props change, but not after initial render. Also you may consider using [getSnapshotBeforeUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate) It is invoked right before the most recently rendered output is committed to e.g. the DOM. It enables your component to capture some information from the DOM (e.g. scroll position) before it is potentially changed. Any value returned by this lifecycle will be passed as a parameter to componentDidUpdate().